# How to solve "make" issue while cross-compiling for Raspberry Pi 4 on the ubuntu

Tags: pi-4, cross-compilation, make

I am trying to cross-compile this ([ultralytics/yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)) project on my ubuntu machine. Since I am compiling it for my another machine "raspberry Pi" so I already installed the toolchain which is in my following path /home/master/tools-master

After cloning the "yolov5" repo, I added the `CMakeLists.txt` file in that. So I had clone this repo in a folder "YOLO" hence the YOLO folder contains the coned repo "yolov5" and "bin" folder for building make files. Within the directory `~/Desktop/YOLO/bin` when I run the following command "`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user/master/Toolchain-RaspberryPi.cmake ../yolov5`" It successfully build the executable file but after this when I run the "`make`" command within the `~/Desktop/YOLO/bin` I get the following error.

```
Scanning dependencies of target yolov5
[100%] Linking CXX executable yolov5
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/yolov5.dir/build.make:69: yolov5] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/yolov5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Can you help me know since I am just on my last edge to build the binary file before transferring it into my rpi and encountering this error

Comment: Do you _have_ to compile on your machine instead of the Pi 4? In my experience, it's best to just start the compiling at night and wake up the next morning to a freshly built executible, althought you may want to do this on the weekend so that if the build fails you can start it again. Also depending on the project (although yours looks rather big) it can take anywhere from 10 minutes to 7 hours (xmrig and OpenCV, respectively)

Comment: @Unsigned_ArduinoBut what's the way to compile the project I mentioned? can you write down the exact steps that would really be helpful for me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the project, but it should be the same steps as on your Ubuntu machine. What I usually do when building is go to the repo root, create a `build` directory, `cd` into it, run `cmake ..` (which runs `cmake` on the repo root, but idk whether that will work with your project, then I just run `make`.